# Confusion in konsole command in linux

Tags: shell, konsole

I was trying to open a new konsole terminal and source file after opening it.
I tried the following command:

```
konsole -T hello --noclose -e "source file"
```

I wanted the terminal to remain open after sourcing the file but even with `--noclose` the new konsole closes. How can I keep the konsole remain open

Comment: The `-e` flag tells `konsole` to run a command *instead* of your shell. You want it to run a command *in* your shell. That's not how to do this. I think this is probably also off-topic for this site and more suited to https://superuser.com/ .